# When running or lifting sails/nodeJS application Error: listen EADDRINUSE

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, terminal, sails.js, port

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1039:14)
    at listen (net.js:1061:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1135:5)
    at Array.async.auto.start [as 0] (/var/www/html/zentiera/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/http/start.js:29:35)
```

While using sails js or node js, The error may create difficulties in newbies of technology.

Answer (score 0):

This specially comes when we try to stop the application using (ctrl+z) 
and unfortunately the error creates while restarting it

```
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sails lift
```

There are 2 methods to recover this situation :

1. Need to kill the previous port

   fuser -k 9002/tcp
2. Declare a different port number in your application

   localhost//config/local.js

   port: process.env.PORT || newPortNumber,